# bit-shift illegal instruction in 64-bit release mode only

Tags: c++, bit-shift, illegal-instruction

I am integrating the PoissonRecon code available [here](http://www.cs.jhu.edu/~misha/Code/PoissonRecon/Version9.0/) into my own mesh manipulation code, but I've been unable to compile the integrated code in x64 because of an "illegal instruction" error in every bit-shift instruction in the Poisson code's octree generation.

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 and my issue occurs only when compiled in x64 and only when in release mode (i.e., it works in x86 debug and release as well as x64 debug).

As an example of one of the bitshift instructions, the following is defined at the top of Octree.inl:

```
template< class NodeData > const int OctNode< NodeData >::DepthShift=5;
template< class NodeData > const int OctNode< NodeData >::OffsetShift = ( sizeof(long long)*8 - DepthShift ) / 3;
template< class NodeData > const int OctNode< NodeData >::DepthMask=(1<<DepthShift)-1; // This variable is correct
template< class NodeData > const int OctNode< NodeData >::OffsetMask=(1<<OffsetShift)-1; // This variable is also correct
template< class NodeData > const int OctNode< NodeData >::OffsetShift1=DepthShift;
template< class NodeData > const int OctNode< NodeData >::OffsetShift2=OffsetShift1+OffsetShift;
template< class NodeData > const int OctNode< NodeData >::OffsetShift3=OffsetShift2+OffsetShift;
```

And these variables are used in the following function:

```
template< class NodeData >
inline unsigned long long OctNode< NodeData >::Index( int depth , const int offset[3] )
{
    unsigned long long idx=0;
    idx |= ( ( (unsigned long long)(depth    ) ) & DepthMask  );
    idx |= ( ( (unsigned long long)(offset[0]) ) & OffsetMask ) << OffsetShift1;
    idx |= ( ( (unsigned long long)(offset[1]) ) & OffsetMask ) << OffsetShift2;
    idx |= ( ( (unsigned long long)(offset[2]) ) & OffsetMask ) << OffsetShift3;
    return idx;
}
```

This function breaks at the line

```
idx |= ( ( (unsigned long long)(offset[0]) ) & OffsetMask ) << OffsetShift1;
```

which I've split down further and found that the issue is the bit-shift itself, i.e. `(var)<<OffsetShift1;` but  this causes an "illegal instruction" error.

Note that OffsetShift1 is simply "5", so this is equivalent to `(var)<<5;` which does work as expected.

A possible workaround is to simply `#define` all of these variables at the top (which does fix the issue), but this does not solve other bit-shift issues such as the following:

```
void _startAndWidth( const TreeOctNode* node , Point3D< Real >& start , Real& width ) const
    {
        LocalDepth d ; LocalOffset off;
        _localDepthAndOffset( node , d , off );
        if (d >= 0) width = Real(1.0 / (1 << d));
        else width = Real( 1.0 * (1<<(-d)) );
        for( int dd=0 ; dd<DIMENSION ; dd++ ) start[dd] = Real( off[dd] ) * width;
    }
```

I've tried to `static_cast<long long>` everything, but it's not an overflow issue. Even stranger, if I break before a bit-shift (while in release mode) and then highlight the operation, the debugger tells me the correct result (for example, `d = 5` in `_startAndWidth`, so `1 << d` returns 32 in the debugger) but actually stepping over the operation causes an "illegal instruction" error.

Since the program works correctly in debug mode, I've tried removing all optimizations in release mode, but I still get the same error. The only workaround I've found is to replace all bit-shift operations with `pow()` instead, and while that works, it seems a `bit` ridiculous.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: Could be a silent code generation bug, which sounds reasonable from the symptoms you describe. I'd suggest you to go ahead and upgrade to MSVC14.1 and Visual Studio 2017 RC or MSVC14 and Visual Studio 2015. Note that Visual Studio 2017 will be released soon and upgrading from a RC shouldn't be a hassle. It's really worth the awesome new installer, it being faster and the included much better compiler.

Comment: I just checked and realized I misspoke. I'm using MSVC 2015, not 2010. I've edited the post.

Comment: At this point I'd be stepping through the assembly.

Comment: Assembly code is even more confusing. The bit-shift assembly code (when in Release x64) is:
`000000014001209F  shlx        r8,rcx,rax `
r8 = garbage (some large int value), rcx = 0, and rax = 5

if I add a print statement before the bit-shift, rax becomes 24, when it should be 5.

Comment: If I remove all optimization, I get an error on the line `template< class NodeData > const int OctNode< NodeData >::DepthMask=(1<<DepthShift)-1;
`. Assembly shows `0000000140001CCB  shlx        eax,eax,ecx` with eax = 1, eax = 1, ecx = 5

Comment: @A.Comer: TBH, I don't understand how you get assembly for an Integral Constant Expression. That should have been fully evaluated by the compiler itself, even in debug mode. That's unavoidable because `OctNode< NodeData >::DepthMask` must be usable as e.g. `char buf[OctNode< NodeData >::DepthMask]` which even in debug mode requires a compile-time constant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it turns out, the .sln file that came with the reconstruction code was set with AVX2, which was unsupported on my machine.

going to `Configuration Properties >> C/C++ >> Code Generation` and setting "Enable Enhanced Instruction Set" to AVX solved the issue.

The assembly code now shows "SHL" instead of "SHLX," so the "illegal instruction" was the actual SHLX command not being available, not an issue with the parameters going into SHLX.

Comment: You saved me a massive amount of head-scratching by answering your own question. Appreciate ya!